# How is my page creating two different types of checkbox?

Tags: asp.net

Got a really weird thing happening on my page. I have some checkbox controls and some of them are rendering like this..

```
<span confirmmodified="true" class="aspNetDisabled"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="ctl00$FormContents$TrackerDetails$OutOfScopeUSQS" id="ctl00_FormContents_TrackerDetails_OutOfScopeUSQS"><label for="ctl00_FormContents_TrackerDetails_OutOfScopeUSQS">Out of scope USQS</label></span>
```

But some of them are rendering like this...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ctl00$FormContents$TrackerDetails$OutOfScopeSQA" id="ctl00_FormContents_TrackerDetails_OutOfScopeSQA"><label for="ctl00_FormContents_TrackerDetails_OutOfScopeSQA">Out of scope USQS</label>
```

See, no span? Cant work out what is going on I have looked at the page and control and doesnt seem like anything different is happening...

UPDATE: [this is the markup]

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AuditStateTracker.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Dashboard.controls.AuditStateTracker" %>
    <div class="grid_12 alpha">
    <h2><asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalisedText, TrackerMigration%>" /></h2>
    </div>
<div class="grid_1">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="OutOfScopeUSQS"  runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalisedText, OutOfScopeUSQS %>" />
</div>
<div class="grid_1" runat="server" ID="divOutOfScopeSQA">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="OutOfScopeSQA" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalisedText, OutOfScopeUSQS %>" />
</div>
<div class="grid_1">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="OutOfScopeRS" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalisedText, OutOfScopeRS %>" />
</div>
<div class="grid_1" runat="server" ID="divRingFencedSQA">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="RingFencedSQA" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalisedText, RingFencedSQA %>" />
</div>
<div class="grid_1">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="RingFencedRS" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalisedText, RingFencedRS %>" />
</div>
<div class="grid_1" runat="server" ID="divBusinessCase">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="BusinessCase" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalisedText, BusinessCase %>" />
</div>
<div class="grid_1" runat="server" ID="divDelisted" visible="false">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Delisted" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalisedText, Delisted %>" />
</div>
```

Comment: what about showing the markup of your aspx page?

Comment: it would be best to see the code before it gets translated to html..

Comment: Is one enabled and one disabled?

Comment: Hi no, they are both enabled....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first checkbox is disabled, the second one isn't; that's how asp.net renders disabled checkboxes.

It's throwing that span on there so asp.net can decorate it with the css class `aspNetDisabled`.  This would allow you to (optionally) style disabled controls differently.

Incidentally, this disabled class is actually [configurable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.disabledcssclass.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of ASP.NET Microsoft used to render the `disabled = "disabled"`attribute for your controls. However, since the HTML 4.01 specification, the disabled attribute is not valid anymore for each type of web control. It is still valid for `input`, but not anymore for `span`.

So what they've done is add a style class (in CSS) which is set to controls when they are disabled. This is also the case with any controls in a diabled control. By default, this style class is called `aspNetDisabled'.

You can actually use a different name for this class, but not for individual controls. The name of this style class can only be set as a static property on the root class `WebControl`, for instance at application start in your `global.asax.cs`.

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebControl.DisabledCssClass = "disabled";
    }
```

More annoying is that for checkboxes, ASP.NET renders a `span` around you checkbox with the defined style class on it.

```
<span disabled="disabled">
    <input id="ctl00_UsecaseContent_ctl01_ctl01_bCVbox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$UsecaseContent$ctl01$ctl01$bCVbox" checked="checked">
</span>
```

When you are using e.g. Bootstrap as your UI framework, and on top of that a checkbox specific framework, such as https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox, this additional `span` can actually break the structure of your HTML checkbox control hierarchy.